# Are ConstraintLayout Animations In ScrollView Possible?

Tags: android, animation, layout, constraints, scrollview

Whenever I try to apply the ConstraintLayout animations on a scrollable constraintLayout I get the error that I can't cast a ScrollView into a ConstraintLayout, and it sounds reasonable.

Is there a way to make a constraint layout scrollable without using ScrollView as parent? That way I'd be able to use its sweet animations.

Thanks.

Comment: Judging from what you are saying "I can't cast a ScrollView into a ConstraintLayout" this sounds more like you are trying to cast a ScrollView into a ConstraintLayout like so: (Kotlin) `myScrollView as ConstraintLayout`, (Java) `(ConstraintLayout) myScrollView`. If that is the case, then your error has nothing to do with animations. Please provide your code for further investigation!

Comment: thanks for the answer mate but the very IDE tells me "that cast can never succeed"

Answer (score 1):

This a common issue with `ConstraintLayout` and `ScrollView / NestedScrollView`. You need to set your `ScrollView` as a parent of `ConstraintLayout` and before you do the transition you need to clone your `ConstraintLayout`

Something like this:

Kotlin:

```
 ConstraintSet().apply {
        clone(constraintLayoutView);
        clone(this, R.layout.activity_animation) // your transition
    }
```

Or if you're using java:

```
  ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
  constraintSet.clone(constraintLayoutView);
  constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_animation);
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I can't seem to clone my constraint layout. android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException. According to Google I can't pass the ID of a View, I need to pass a Layout only.

ConstraintSet().apply {
                        clone(context, R.id.login_constraint) //ERROR
                        clone(context, R.layout.activity_login_transition)
                        applyTo(resources.getLayout(R.layout.activity_login) as ConstraintLayout)
                    }

Comment: I'm checking the documentation and there is a method `clone` that receives `context` and `constraintLayoutId` as a parameters, and also you can call that method just with the reference to the layout view. `clone(yourConstraintLayoutView)`, you can try that. Here's the doc. I'm sure is something about that https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#clone(Context,%20int)

Comment: oh yeah, I just updated the answer then, with the right implementation :D

Answer (score 1):

CONSTRAINT SET FOR A CONSTRAINT LAYOUT THAT'S NOT PARENT

I figured it out. This works wonders. I think this may be useful to other developers because I assume it's pretty normal to use a ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView, for example in login screens.

So now I have 2 Xmls right? The "original" and the transition one.

```
Original: <ScrollView> <ConstraintLayout><ConstraintLayout> <ScrollView>
Transition: <ConstraintLayout></ConstraintLayout>
```

Transition XML has no ScrollView because I need to clone a full layout (my transition layout) inside a ViewGroup (ScrollView's child, my constraint layout). If you try to clone a child constraint layout into another child constraint layout it crashes with a .getChild() method, don't know why. But you can clone a ConstraintLayout layout to a ConstraintLayout view.

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_login_transition) // here I'm cloning the whole transition layout
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(login_constraint) //this is only for animation
constraintSet.applyTo(login_constraint) // and here I'm applying it only to my constraint layout. 'login_constraint' is my constraint's ID
```

And that's it. Hope it worked for you too.

Thanks to Ezequiel Zanetta